# app.UseEndpoints in .NET 8's top-level program.cs with combination of Areas

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web app where ASP.NET Core Identity is within an area called `Identity`, and the main web app is without an area. On top of this, I want a  custom frontend set of pages that come with their npm packages and gulped JS and CSS files that I do not want to mix with main application. So I want another area called `Landing`. It will be a single endless scroll page, and security is not needed in that area.

I have this in my `program.cs`:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(name: "Identity", areaName: "Identity", pattern: "Identity/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Dashboard}/{action=DashboardV3}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

*Because I couldn't figure out the `new app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");` syntax.*

**Issue:**

Issue is that if I go the the root URL such as `localhost:20202/` or `myap.com/`, I get an error/404 page. I have to explicitly hit a controller in either under Identity Area or in the base application.

I'm not sure at this stage if it is wise to move everything to areas but I do have to add the Landing area now and my routing is not working as expected. I assumed that if a user just goes to `localhost:20202`, he's be redirected to the default page (controller/action) which will be marked Authorized and he'll be sent to Identity/*/Login. But I have to explicitly specify the url for base app as: `localhost:20202/Revenue/AssetList` to trigger everything.

**Required**

- Ultimately, base URL should point to `/Landing/Home/index.html`
- Login button there will redirect to `/Revenue/Dashboard` (no area)
- Authorize will intercept and send to `/Identity/*/Login`

That is what I want to map in routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Issue is that if I go the the root URL such as localhost:20202/ or
> myap.com/, I get an error/404 page. I have to explicitly hit a
> controller in either under Identity Area or in the base application.

According to your scenario here is the thing, since your Landing area is a custom frontend set of pages that come with their npm packages and gulped JS and CSS files which mostly a [static file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root), so you don't need controller routing.

Instead, you should configure static file serving for the Landing area's assets like HTML, CSS, and JS. Use [MapFallbackToDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutebuilderextensions.mapfallback?view=aspnetcore-8.0) with the appropriate directory path for your Landing files.

For instance, you can do as following:

```
endpoints.MapAreaFallbackToDirectory(name: "Landing", areaName: "Landing", directory: "Landing/dist");
```

And then configure your static file resource:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "Landing")
    ),
    RequestPath = "/Landing"
});
```

**Note:** Check the [static file configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root).

Therefore, altogether your Identity, your dashborard and landing page's route configuration should be as following:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(name: "Identity", areaName: "Identity", pattern: "Identity/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "landing",
        pattern: "Landing/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"
    );
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Dashboard}/{action=DashboardV3}"
    );
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/Landing/{**slug}", "Landing/Home/index.html");
});
```

**Note:** "/Landing" is the literal path prefix. Requests that start with "/Landing" will match this route.
keep in mind, {**slug} parameter placeholder would captures the rest of the URL as a single parameter named "slug." You can [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#route-templates).